# flash cannot access the webservice

Tags: flash, apache-flex, iis, crossdomain.xml

I am using flex/actionscript. i have created a webservice with following path http://192.168.0.110/cgi/reg.cgi? When i run the above url its works fine. but when i use it using httpservice and send method it is giving me error. event: registerFailure
Error description: HTTP update error

```
mHttpService = new HTTPService();
mHttpService.url = mWebServiceUrl;
mHttpService.method = "POST";
mHttpService.addEventListener("result", httpResult);
mHttpService.addEventListener("fault", httpFault);


var request:Object = new Object();
request.username = user;
request.identity = id;
mHttpService.cancel();
mHttpService.send(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand the webservice should be of format.
eg: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL (This works try!).

And link for this web service is page is http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx.

So, i think. There is problem with the web service link.
Hope , this helps.

Comment: i am working with open source adobe cirrus.. if u can go through it  it will be of gr8 help to me..i am sorry to use the wrong word webservice. it is httprequest that will do a post on this url and fetch the response. the page works fine if i run it on my server 192.168.0.209.. but gives error when i run it on my local machine.. i have hosted the cgi both on local and 209.. when i run my app on local it will access local cgi.. if i run it on 209 it will access 209 cgi service.. THE PROBLEM IS WITH LOCAL ONE.. IT DOESNT RETURN A RESPONSE.